# Log4 logger rolling appender

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender` and facing strange issue.
When I set log file name to `process.log` it does not roll over but when I set log file name to `process1.log` or `process2.log` it works fine and rolls over after given max file size.

```
log4j.appender.ProcessLogAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ProcessLogAppender.File=D:/logs/process.log

log4j.appender.ProcessLogAppender.Append=true
log4j.appender.ProcessLogAppender.MaxFileSize=30KB
log4j.appender.ProcessLogAppender.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.ProcessLogAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ProcessLogAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.util.ApplicationLogger=ALL,ProcessLogAppender
```

Comment: can you post your log4j.properties/log4j.xml here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create java logging class [like this](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=491) properly and read your property file through it. Restart server. These will solve this problem.

These lines are very important.

```
private static Properties loggerProperties = LoggerClassName.read(“log4j.properties”);

static Logger validation =
Logger.getLogger(LoggerClassName.class);

static {
  PropertyConfigurator.configure(loggerProperties);
  validation.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
}
```